# How to create a List of constants

Tags: vb.net, list, constants, shared

I have a class inside another class that has public access called `SampleRating`.
There is a list of objects of the type of `SampleRating` called `SampleRatings`.
The data stored in the list items should never be changed after it is initially set, only queried. The list itself should also never be changed.

What is the correct way of making the list and the values therein, have a read-only property? I tried `Const` or `Static` but the compiler complains about both.

My class and List:

```
Public Class Foo
    Public Class SampleRating
        Enum SampleRateSetting As Byte
            SR0 = 1
            SR1 = 2
            SR2 = 4
            SR3 = 8
        End Enum

        Public Setting As SampleRateSetting
        Public Noise As UInt16
        Public Bandwidth As UInt16
        Public SampleRate As UInt32
        Public BinWidth As Double

        Public Shared Function FindSetting(Setting As SampleRateSetting) As Predicate(Of SampleRating)
            Return Function(Rating As SampleRating) Rating.Setting = Setting
        End Function
    End Class

    Public Shared SampleRatings As New List(Of SampleRating) From {
       New SampleRating With {.Setting = SampleRating.SampleRateSetting.SR0, .SampleRate = 100189, .BinWidth = 196, .Bandwidth = 26000, .Noise = 467},
       New SampleRating With {.Setting = SampleRating.SampleRateSetting.SR1, .SampleRate = 12524, .BinWidth = 25, .Bandwidth = 6262, .Noise = 260},
       New SampleRating With {.Setting = SampleRating.SampleRateSetting.SR2, .SampleRate = 1566, .BinWidth = 3.1, .Bandwidth = 783, .Noise = 100},
       New SampleRating With {.Setting = SampleRating.SampleRateSetting.SR3, .SampleRate = 196, .BinWidth = 0.38, .Bandwidth = 98, .Noise = 38}
   }

   ' Have also tried the below instead, with no luck
   Public Shared SampleRatings As New ReadOnlyCollection(Of SampleRating)(New List(Of SampleRating)() From {
       New SampleRating With {.Setting = SampleRating.SampleRateSetting.SR0, .SampleRate = 100189, .BinWidth = 196, .Bandwidth = 26000, .Noise = 467},
       New SampleRating With {.Setting = SampleRating.SampleRateSetting.SR1, .SampleRate = 12524, .BinWidth = 25, .Bandwidth = 6262, .Noise = 260},
       New SampleRating With {.Setting = SampleRating.SampleRateSetting.SR2, .SampleRate = 1566, .BinWidth = 3.1, .Bandwidth = 783, .Noise = 100},
       New SampleRating With {.Setting = SampleRating.SampleRateSetting.SR3, .SampleRate = 196, .BinWidth = 0.38, .Bandwidth = 98, .Noise = 38}
    })

    Function Shared Bar() As Boolean
        ' Should NOT be able to change the list or list item members here.
    End Function
End Class 'End of Foo
```

Comment: That's the purpose of a read-only property.

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf How do I apply that in this context? (I'm a .net newb) on the list? the class? The members? All? Thanks.

Comment: Playing about a bit, I can assign `ReadOnly` to the List but not to the objects on the List. As classes (and Lists?) are reference types I think this means the `ReadOnly` property does not propagate to the Items on the List.

Comment: If you dont want them to change the list, dont expose the list - return a copy, perhaps in a RO Collection.  If the items use RO Props, the items in it cant be changed.  But also consider constructing a collection class which provides whatever services are needed (find, sort, count, contains etc).  It depends on whether the *list* or the *list items* never change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure the List and the list items are both read only, you'll have to do 2 things.

First, you'll need to use a [ReadOnlyCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a list.  Basically, you create your list normally using a standard List object and once it's completed, you can call the [AsReadOnly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method on your List to get a ReadOnlyCollection.

The second thing you'll have to do is to create [read-only properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2b2c2ka.aspx).  Depending on your needs, you may also consider adding a private setter for your property... by definition, it won't be a read-only property, but the setter won't be exposed outside your class so it will prevent any other object from changing the value of your property.

**UPDATE**

You mentioned that the property should not be modified from the Bar function...  The problem here is that you're trying to prevent modifications in `SampleRatings` in a class that is also used to initialize the `SampleRatings`.

Notice the private setter in the following example.  When it's private, you can't initialize the `SampleRatings`, but if you make it public, you'll be able to change it in the `Bar` function.

```
Public Class Foo
    Public Class SampleRating
        Private _noise As UInt16
        Public Property Noise() As UInt16
            Get
                Return _noise
            End Get
            Private Set(ByVal value As UInt16)
                _noise = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class

    'If the noise is read-only (or has a private setter), you won't be able to set the noise value here...
    Public Shared SampleRatings As New ReadOnlyCollection(Of SampleRating)(New List(Of SampleRating)() From {
        New SampleRating With {.Noise = 467},
        New SampleRating With {.Noise = 260},
        New SampleRating With {.Noise = 100},
        New SampleRating With {.Noise = 38}
     })

    Shared Function Bar()

        'Doesn't work
        SampleRatings.Remove(SampleRatings.First())

        'Doesn't work
        SampleRatings.First().Noise = 1

    End Function

End Class
```

You didn't mention why you want to prevent modification in your list in the first place...  if you want to prevent modification from external assemblies, you should consider declaring your setter as `Friend` (see [Access Levels in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76453kax.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)).

Comment: thanks for the added info. Im reading up on your suggestions now. Looking at it now though, it seems it wouldn't prevent other methods in class `Foo` from changing the underlying list?

Comment: Tried `Public Shared SampleRatings As New ReadOnlyCollection(Of SampleRating)(New List(Of SampleRating) From { New SampleRating With {.Setting = ... ...}})` But this still does not prevent `Foo` methods from changing the data, only methods that use `Foo`

Comment: Can you update your question with an example you this specific problem?

Comment: Added Bar() & ReadOnlyCollection attempt, is that what you meant?

Comment: Now I understand what you want to do but I'm afraid it won't be possible to prevent modifications in a list in the same class you'll initialize it. See answer update.